# Breeze vs. Spire: Can/should I combine them?

Tags: scala, scala-breeze, spire

I use breeze's collections (namely `DenseVector`), in which I have integers and doubles and the like, and use them a little like you might use numpy's arrays. I stumbled upon https://github.com/non/spire. My impression is, it is not so strong on collection, but stronger on types that I might want to put inside of collections - e.g. `Interval` sounds awesome. Is my impression right and would be combining them a good idea?

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/40474914/4533188 I learned that Breeze uses [netlib-java](https://github.com/fommil/netlib-java/) to be really fast. Would I destroy that speed if I put descendants of `AnyRef` (in this case from Spire) into the `DenseVector`s back-end Arrays instead of descendants of `AnyVal`?